# Facebook badge Image not showing up in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

That's kind height of IE bugs, I am adding **Facebook Like Badge** to my website, it works perfectly on all other browsers. But in **Internet Explorer**, it simply does't show's the image.

Here is the URL to image: https://www.facebook.com/profile/pic.php?oid=AWx871Lpn7AYEi4T-uzfdAeOryMPDODTbt9fflde-TT-bwSrfhACl0_-eGXhWVFwV-o&size=square

It will show up every where expect IE. The worst thing is it doesn't show up in **IE 10** as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Content-Type` is `image/jpeg` but the image itself is a GIF. You can reproduce this by simply renaming a GIF locally with a `.jpeg` extension and then trying to open it in IE. You'll get the box with a red X. If you name the file with a `.gif` extension, it'll open normally.